# Allocating memory for first level cache per a session

Tags: java, hibernate

When some of sessions fetch many entities, these entities are stored in the first-level cache and this can lead to out of memory problems and server crash.

This may happen for many different reasons, like a developer writing a bug in his query, or allowing setting of incorrect parameters on the screen.

The problem I intend to target is NOT to resolve the problem on a single application level, but rather to prevent the server crash. It is perfectly fine if the application operation will fail.

Is there a way to prevent Hibernate from allocating entities per a session after reaching some maximum?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, also the first level cache is needed to do dirty checking for managed entities. Instead of trying to shoehorn a solution in which will ultimately lead to other issues (changes not persisted or unknow references etc.) fix the queries.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe try to use a Hibernate `Interceptor` to maintain a counter per session and throw an exception if it exceeds a threshold, but there is no builtin way of doing what you want.

Comment: Is there a different interceptor per a session?

Comment: Ok I found session scoped interceptor. Thanks!